# Looking for a simple way to manipulate one column of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Given

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}}
```

I want to get

```
{{c, b}, {a, d}}
```

with one simple expression.  Is this possible?

Comment: With `m = {{a, b}, {c, d}}`, use `m[[;; , 1]] = m[[Dimensions[m][[1]] ;; 1 ;; -1, 1]]`?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`SubsetMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetMap.html) for this:

```
l = {{a, b}, {c, d}}

SubsetMap[Reverse, l, {All, 1}]
```

> `{{c, b}, {a, d}}`

That is, `Reverse` and replace the list of elements comprised of the `1`nth element of `All` rows of `l`.

There are bound to be many other solutions.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest making use of function argument destructuring. The required munger can be written directly from the problem statement. No need to dig out arcane knowledge of list manipulation.

```
mung[{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}] := {{c, b}, {a, d}}
m = {{a, b}, {c, d}}; mung[m]
```

> `{{c, b}, {a, d}}`

Answer (score 4):

```
Diagonal /@ {Reverse[m], m}
```

> {{c, b}, {a, d}}

```
Transpose @ MapAt[Reverse, Transpose[m], {1}]
```

> {{c, b}, {a, d}}

Answer (score 3):

Your question is tagged both "list-manipulation" and "matrices". Other answers have given answers treating this as a nested list, but if you want to do it with matrix operations, the two columns of the resulting matrix are `{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}.{{a, b}, {c, d}}.{{1},{0}}` and `{{a, b}, {c, d}}.{{0},{1}}`, so you can them combine those two column vectors into a matrix to get the answer.